# dynamiodb add object in list inside a object inside a list nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I've this type of objects in DynamoDB, and I want to add a device to it.

```
     {
        "user": "user2",
        "pass": "pass2",
        "name": "persona1",
        "lastname": "person2",
        "places":
        [
        {
          "name": "bedroom",
          "devices": [{
                      "name": "Lampara",
                      "chip": "esp8266_D98FF1"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Puerta",
                      "chip": "esp8266_1F852F"
                    }]
        }
      ]
  }
```

I want to add a new device in bedroom like

```
{
     "name": "bed",
      "chip": "esp8266_44444F"
}
```

How can I add an object to Dynamodb when it's so nested?

EDIT: I solve seaching the index of the zone and making this request.

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.session.Item.zonas.length; i++) {
  if (req.session.Item.zonas.nombre == req.body.zona){
    index = i;
  }
}
var devicetoAdd = {
     "nombre": req.body.nombre,
     "chip": req.body.cod
};
var params = {
    TableName: "usuarios",
    Key:{
        "user": req.session.user
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set zonas[" + index+ "].devices = list_append(zonas[" + index+ "].devices, :vals)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":vals": [devicetoAdd]
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
```

Comment: Why these tags regarding to Amazon services?

Comment: What happens if you have two `places` with the same name?

Comment: I can't have places with the same name. I edited my ask because I don't mention dynamodb in it, but I want to add a device in a place in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that object can contains more than one places with the same name, you can use the function `forEach`.

```js
var obj = {  TableName: "usuarios",  Item: {    "user": "user2",    "pass": "pass2",    "name": "persona1",    "lastname": "person2",    "places": [{      "name": "bedroom",      "devices": [{          "name": "Lampara",          "chip": "esp8266_D98FF1"        },        {          "name": "Puerta",          "chip": "esp8266_1F852F"        }      ]    }]  }};

obj.Item.places.forEach(p => {
  if (p.name === 'bedroom') {
    p.devices.push({ "name": "bed", "chip": "esp8266_44444F" })
  }
});

console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```